# How do you specify return type of Promise or Next() in async function using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

If a function returns either the Res.Status(201).json(Promise Mongo.save()) or a next(Error) how do specify the return type? Lint warns

*The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise type.ts*

```
const postVacation = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<IVacationMongo> | NextFunction => {
  const vacation: IVacation = {
    id: undefined,
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
  };
  try {
    const newVacation: Promise<IVacationMongo> = vacationData.addVacation(vacation);
    res.status(201).json(newVacation);
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new HttpException(500, error.toString()));
  }
};
```

*edit - No need to return next, can then use `Promise<void>` as return type.

Comment: `async` functions *always* return a promise. The actual return type would be a promise of whatever `NextFunction` *returns*. But why do you `return next(...)`?

Comment: For that matter you don't actually return anything in the other path, so `Promise<IVacationMongo>` is wrong too.

Comment: Thanks, im new to the next concept. To me then its remove the return, it doesnt need async and make it void

Comment: Well you could keep `async` and `await` the result of your query. At the moment you're JSONifying a *promise*, which doesn't make any sense. But yes, you can remove the return.

Comment: Return type is then Promise<void> ?

Comment: For an `async` function with no `return`s? Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` functions *always* return a `Promise`

## Fix

So change `Promise<IVacationMongo> | NextFunction` to `Promise<IVacationMongo> | Promise<NextFunction>` or even better `Promise<IVacationMongo | NextFunction>`.